# Cannot receive ifconfig data from exec_command with Paramiko

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I have written a code that connects to the virtual machine (using SSH with Paramiko) and executes several commands. But I do not get the result from the `ifconfig` command (the rest of the commands still get normal)
info:

- Python version: 3.7
- Paramiko version: 2.4.2
- OS: Linux 4.18

My code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paramiko
import getpass


def ssh_connect(host, port):

    USERNAME = input("username: ")
    PASSWORD = getpass.getpass("password: ")
    CMDs = ['pwd', 'ifconfig', 'lsblk']
    try:
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh_client.connect(host, port=port, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
        for CMD in CMDs:
            print(f"{USERNAME}@{host}$ {CMD}")
            _, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(CMD.strip())
            data_array_return = stdout.read().decode()
            for line in data_array_return.split("\n"):
                print(str(line))
        ssh_client.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def main():
    HOST = input("hostname: ")
    PORT = int(input("port: "))
    ssh_connect(HOST, PORT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

my output

```
ctnguyenvn[paraSSH]$ ./paramiko_ssh_simple.py 
hostname: 192.168.145.10
port: 22
username: linux-victim
password: 
linux-victim@192.168.145.10$ pwd
/home/linux-victim

linux-victim@192.168.145.10$ ifconfig

linux-victim@192.168.145.10$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   30G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  300M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 27.7G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

I don't think my code is wrong. How do I get results from the `ifconfig` command?

`stderr` for `ifconfig` shows:

> bash: ifconfig: command not found

Comment: Did you try reading `stderr`?

Comment: thanks, the result in stderr: `bash: ifconfig: command not found`, but I don't understand why the output error while the result (`ifconfig` command) in the virtual machine succeeds

Answer (score 0):

Enter the full path of ifconfig.

you can get it with this command:

```
which ifconfig
```

Comment: Thanks, I sent the `echo $PATH` command and the result `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin` does not contain the `ifconfig` command (/usr/sbin/ifconfig).